# Powershell alias for "cd .."

Tags: powershell, alias, cd

I want to create an alias for `cd ..` as `..` in powershell.

I've tried to following variations but to no avail.

```
Set-Alias ".." "cd .."
Set-Alias ".." { set-location "cd .." }
Set-Alias ".." { set-location ".." }
```

Comment: there is a powershell operator that uses that `..` sequence - the range operator. i would pick something else. [*grin*] perhaps just `up` or `uu`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would have to be a function, since it has arguments:

```
function .. { set-location .. }
```

There's actually a function already called "cd.." with no spaces, to mimic cmd.  So you could also do:

```
set-alias .. cd..
```